# Does the Bank of England have the ability to set reserve requirements for commercial banks?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, central-banking

I’ve been studying about monetary policy comittee.

Comment: Probably, but they're zero right now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Bank of England is the regulatory authority in the UK which sets reserve requirements for commercial banks.

A short overview of the Bank of England's history regarding money supply and reserve requirements can be found here:
http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/noftp/faculty/bergin/econ320/BOE.pdf

More information on how commercial banks hold reserves can be found in the famous Red Book:
https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/sterling-monetary-framework/annual-report-2017-18

Although the UK does not at present have a minimum reserve requirement, commercial banks nonetheless must be well capitalised in accordance with BoE regulation on the counter-cyclical capital buffer. (I mention this because one reason central banks have minimum reserve requirements is also in relation to capital requirements/buffering, as well as traditional liquidity and rate setting reasons.)